# Binding data from GridPanel to Component in Extjs 4.*

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

My web application is very simple, two panel - the first one is GridPanel that retrieve data from json store (and it has 2 collumns: 'Name' and 'Phonenumber'). The second one contains two label, and all what I want is when I click a row in 1st panel, the data of the clicked record will be fill to the two label of the second panel!
How can these panel connect to others?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Grid data binding example](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/binding-with-classes.html) in kitchen sink?